# Convert into HTML checkboxes using JSON values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

This JSON is dynamic, coming from API and I can't change it. I want to get table.cc value and convert it into HTML checkbox.

```
let table = {
  id: 1,
  value: "abc",
  height: 1080,
  width: 1920,
  cc: "{"c08":false,"c07":true}"
}

let headers = Object.keys(table);
let rows = Object.values(table);
let cc = table.cc ? JSON.parse(table.cc) : null;

if(cc) {
  let output = Object.entries(cc).map(([key, value]) => {
    return `<input type="checkbox" checked=${value}>
            <label>${key}</label>`;
  }).join('');
  console.log(output);
  rows[4] = `${output}`; // I am getting a string. I am unable to convert it into HTML markup.
}
```

Since I am looping over Object.values(table), I want to change only the table.cc to get HTML checkboxes. So, in the case of the above example table.cc should have 2 checkboxes in HTML and the second one should be checked since the value is true. The label should be the key.
Any ideas?

I have put a link in stackblitz to edit the code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5dtdjt

Comment: are you sure you are using react? React is a library you have to import, it is not in the browsers as a default.

Comment: React is already there. This is a stateless component. I havenot showed in this snippet that I have imported React to minimize the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working after some fixes. You should not add html tags as strings in JSX. And a Fragment needs to be used as parent element.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
                           --------

...

  if (cc) {
    let output = Object.entries(cc).map(([key, value]) => {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={value} />
          <label>{key}</label>
        </Fragment>
      )
    });
    rows[4] = output
```

Comment: thank you @gazdagergo. It worked like a charm. Thanks.